# Linux Centos TeamCity build agent fails to restore nuget packages

Tags: .net-core, teamcity, centos7

When the Teamcity build agent executes my bash script it fails to restore nuget packages with following message:

```
dotnet restore my-solution.sln
```

```
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.401/NuGet.targets(525,5): error : 
'NUGET_PACKAGES' must contain an absolute path 'C:\temp\nugetcache'.
```

The user running the build agent does not have sudo rights.

If I logon to the machine with same account and run the script from the build agents work dir it works fine.

So it only happens when the build is triggered from Team city server.

I guess this has something to do with permissions but I am stuck...

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution. Parent project set env var 'NUGET_PACKAGES'

Cleared that and everything works fine!